# Getting response body from a NodeJS Express POST response

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm running into an issue with NodeJS and Express which seems like it should be "Hello World" simple, but has been stumping me all day.  Here's my NodeJS POST code:

```
app.post('/evaluateScore', (req, res) => {
  output = calculators
    .evaluateScore({
      handicap: req.body.handicap,
      score: req.body.score,
      rating: req.body.rating,
      slope: req.body.slope,
      holes: req.body.holes
    })
   console.log(output)
   res.mydata = {}
   res.mydata.output = output
   console.log("res.mydata.output: " + res.mydata.output)
   res.end()
})
```

And here's the client code that calls it:

```
post('/evaluateScore', { handicap, score, rating, slope, holes })
    .then(({ mydata }) => {
        console.log(mydata)
        Evaluator.querySelector('.result').value = mydata.output
        })
```

My problem is that no matter what I've tried to do with my {output} value, which is generated correctly in the POST server-side, I cannot send it back successfully to the client.  I've tried all kinds of things:

```
res.json
res.send
res.data
```

I've found threads claiming that each of those work in some way, but the only thing that the client ever seems to have access to is the 'status', which I can either send with a res.sendStatus(XXX) call, or will be 200 by default.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Errors? What do the `console.log()` lines reveal?

Does this not work?

```
app.post('/evaluateScore', (req, res) => {
  output = calculators
    .evaluateScore({
      handicap: req.body.handicap,
      score: req.body.score,
      rating: req.body.rating,
      slope: req.body.slope,
      holes: req.body.holes
    });
   console.log(output);
   res.json(output);
});
```

Also, maybe this in the caller:

```
post('/evaluateScore', { handicap, score, rating, slope, holes })
    .then(mydata => {
        console.log(mydata);
        Evaluator.querySelector('.result').value = mydata
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I think you've gotten me closer.

Comment: Here's my updated code right now.  The **output** is a string, "Hello World!"

Server:
    `console.log(output)
    res.json({ "result": output }).send()`

Client:
    `post('/evaluateScore', { handicap, score, rating, slope, holes })
     .then(mydata => {
      console.log(mydata.json)
      Evaluator.querySelector('.result').value = mydata.json.result
     })`

In the developer console in the browser, the **console.log()** shows as

`function json()`

But I don't see a way to get the "Hello World!" string from it.

Comment: Got it!!  

Thank you again Grant, you got me past my confusion in the caller syntax, and here's the code that worked.  

Server:  

   `res.json({"result": output})
   res.end()`

Client:  

    `post('/evaluateScore', { handicap, score, rating, slope, holes })
     .then(data => data.json())
     .then(json => {
      Evaluator.querySelector('.result').value = json.result
     })`

Comment: @LeeRosenberg Glad my bumbling got you closer. Hard to post a solid answer going from memory, away from an editor. :)